# NLP TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to do typo correction in Turkish. For this, I am using the [**turkishnlp**](https://pypi.org/project/turkishnlp/) script but am getting "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable". I've looked into it but couldn't figure it out.

```
from turkishnlp import detector 
obj = detector.TurkishNLP()
 
lwords = obj.list_words("vri kümsi idrae edre ancaka daha güezl oalbilir")
obj.auto_correct(lwords)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-15278e4ef5a3> in <module>
      1 lwords = obj.list_words("vri kümsi idrae edre ancaka daha güezl oalbilir")
----> 2 obj.auto_correct(lwords)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\turkishnlp\detector.py in auto_correct(self, word_list)
    127 
    128     def auto_correct(self, word_list):
--> 129         return list(map(self.__correct, word_list))
    130 
    131     def __correct(self, word):

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\turkishnlp\detector.py in __correct(self, word)
    136         Try to find the best spelling correction for this word
    137         """
--> 138         candidates = (self.__known(self.__edits0(word)) or
    139                       self.__known(self.__edits1(word)) or
    140                       self.__known(self.__edits2(word)) or

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\turkishnlp\detector.py in __known(self, words)
    148         :return: Return the subset of words that allready exists in the dictionary
    149         """
--> 150         return {w for w in words if w in self.counted_words}
    151 
    152     def __edits0(self, word):

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\turkishnlp\detector.py in <setcomp>(.0)
    148         :return: Return the subset of words that allready exists in the dictionary
    149         """
--> 150         return {w for w in words if w in self.counted_words}
    151 
    152     def __edits0(self, word):

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I would greatly appreciate any help! Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: before directly using obj.auto_correct(lwords) just add **obj.download()** and **obj.create_word_set()** as per the instructions given for the turkishnlp package in pypi.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder but now there is the bandwidth error.. HTTPError: HTTP Error 509: Bandwidth Limit Exceeded. Any ideas why?

Comment: I too observed this, may the site internal problem, wait for few hours and try again.